# Google Dataflow warnings when using Service & Host Projects, Shared VPCs & Firewall Rules

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I currently run a Cloud Dataflow Streaming Job via the Python SDK.
To explain my setup:

- one service project, "miles-qa"

  - hosts the dataflow job
- one host project, "miles-qa-networking"

  - hosts the network, "miles-qa-vpc"
  - hosts the subnetwork the dataflow job targets

For example, some of the args I'm calling my job with:

```
--project <host project name>
--network <shared vpc project name>
--subnetwork "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<shared vpc project name>/regions/<region job is running in service project>/subnetworks/<name of subnetwork in shared vpc project>"
--service_account_email=<service account with Compute Network User permission for both projects, shared vpc network & subnetwork>
```

When running, I receive the following error:

```
The network miles-qa-vpc doesn't have rules that open TCP ports 1-65535 for internal connection with other VMs. Only rules with a target tag 'dataflow' or empty target tags set apply. If you don't specify such a rule, any pipeline with more than one worker that shuffles data will hang. Causes: No firewall rules associated with your network.
```

However, firewall rules are configured to allow access.
I believe this an issue outside of the Apache Beam SDK; this error is not found in the GitHub for the DataflowRunner or ApacheBeam Python(or Java) SDK.

As suggested in the warning, the job will hang once we perform larger shuffles across nodes.

I've tried the following:

1. Only passing "--subnetwork" without "--network" only modifies the warning to state "default" instead of "miles-qa-vpc", which sounds like a logging error to me.
2. Firewall rules have been configured to:

   - allow all traffic
   - allow all internal traffic
   - allow all traffic with the source tag 'dataflow'
   - allow all traffic with the target tag 'dataflow'
3. Service Account has been configured to have Compute Network User permissions in both projects.
4. Ensured subnetwork is in the same region as the job.
5. Network in the service project is happily serving a dedicated cluster for other purposes in the host project.

It genuinely seems like the spawned Compute Instances are not gaining the configuration.

I expect the Dataflow job not to report the firewall issue and successfully deal with shuffling (GroupBys etc.)

Comment: This seems pretty complex. Have you filed a support ticket for this?

Comment: @user3521195 Any luck resolving this, i am also facing similar warnings and my dataflow jobs are failing.